# After setting initial state, click on update function getting same value

Tags: reactjs

I am updating a state by click on button. before there is a default value as well. when i click on update button same value updates again. any one show me the correct way to handle? for my case `0` and `1` are same value

here is the code :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const names = ["Arif", "Afi", "Afzil", "Adil"];
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [name, setName] = useState(names[num]);

  const Update = (i) => {
    setNum(num + i);
    setName(names[num]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      {num} <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => Update(1)}>Update</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => Update(-1)}>Downdate</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-marco-tvkfb?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: setNum will not set the value instantly. it will only set its value in its next render, please go through react useState hooks docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setNum(num + i);
setName(names[num]);
```

Here you first set the state via `setNum` to `num + 1`. But `num` is a local variable. Think of it as a snapshot of your state's value at the time your component rendered. `num` won't have the new value of the updated state until the next render.

So when you do this the first time:

```
setNum(num + i);
```

You set `0 + 1` in state, but `num` is still `0`.

Then you do:

```
setName(names[num]);
```

And since num is still `0`, the name being set in state doesn't change.

---

The real problem here is that you have too much state. The name can be derived from the `num`, so you don't need to store the name in state at all.

For example:

```
export default function App() {
  const names = ["Arif", "Afi", "Afzil", "Adil"];
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  // removed [name, setName] entirely

  const Update = (i) => {
    setNum(num + i);
  };

  // lookup name using the stateful value `num`
  const name = names[num]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      {num} <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => Update(1)}>Update</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => Update(-1)}>Downdate</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that there is only one state, and we simply look up the the name as we render.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-night-vkimu)

Comment: I agree. but I am getting this error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot add node 1 because a node with that id is already in the Store.` do you have any idea? when i add the if condition `https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-gauss-njomz?file=/src/App.js:206-345` refresh and check the  console by clicking the button

Comment: @3gwebtrain That error seems to be coming from the React developer tools, which aren't present in production. It may have something to with how code sandbox is including react. I'm not sure what it means, but it doesn't seem to cause problems, and it probably will not be present in a standalone react app. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-tdd-92f2h?file=/src/App.js:0-629

```
const names = ["Arif", "Afi", "Afzil", "Adil"];

export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [name, setName] = useState(names[num]);

  const Update = (i) => setNum(num + i);

  useEffect(() => {
    setName(names[num]);
  }, [num, setName]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      {num} <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => Update(1)}>Update</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => Update(-1)}>Downdate</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a working example. React state updates are asynchronous, so calling them one after another in the same function tends to cause issues. In this case, when you call `setName` inside your `update` function, `num` is still the old value.

When you want state to change depending on some other state, you should use the `useEffect` hook. Heres's the relevant doc:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

EDIT: Alex Wayne is right and you do not need two separate states. Still, do read on useEffect for when you want to do side-effects like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because they happen "at the same time". So, num still has the same value when you try to setName.

The recommendation would be:

```js
 const Update = (i) => {
    const newValue = (num + i) % names.length;
    setNum(newValue);
    setName(names[newValue]);
  };
```

You can see how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-danilo-h3cf2?file=/src/App.tsx:227-356